# How to extract and display the preference node from the below JSON

Tags: rest-assured-jsonpath

JSON:

```
[
    {
        "name": "TEST",
        "desc": "",
        "descData": null,
        "closed": false,
        "idOrganization": null,
        "idEnterprise": null,
        "limits": null,
        "pinned": null,
        "shortLink": "0vww",
        "powerUps": [],
        "dateLastActivity": "2020-02-20T17:35:34.008Z",
        "idTags": [],
        "datePluginDisable": null,
        "creationMethod": null,
        "ixUpdate": null,
        "enterpriseOwned": false,
        "idBoardSource": "1232131",
        "id": "1231231123",
        "starred": false,
        "url": "test",
        "prefs": {
            "permissionLevel": "private",
            "hideVotes": false,
            "voting": "disabled",
            "comments": "members",
            "invitations": "members",
            "selfJoin": false,
            "cardCovers": true,
            "isTemplate": false,
            "cardAging": "regular",
            "calendarFeedEnabled": false,
            "background": "5c2f9de25f4d0845100f81b3",
            "backgroundImage": "TEST",
            "backgroundTile": false,
            "backgroundBrightness": "light",
            "backgroundBottomColor": "#635e5d",
            "backgroundTopColor": "#f4f4f3",
            "canBePublic": true,
            "canBeEnterprise": true,
            "canBeOrg": true,
            "canBePrivate": true,
            "canInvite": true
        },
        "subscribed": false,
        "labelNames": {
            "green": "",
            "yellow": "",
            "orange": "",
            "red": "",
            "purple": "",
            "blue": "",
            "sky": "",
            "lime": "",
            "pink": "",
            "black": ""
        },
        "dateLastView": "2020-05-24T20:26:00.621Z",
        "shortUrl": "https://trello.com",
        "templateGallery": null,
        "premiumFeatures": []
    }
]
```

The below code fails when trying to extract user preferences node-

```
    System.out.println("User Preferences are below: \n");
    LinkedHashMap <String,String> tmplist = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    tmplist.putAll(js.get("prefs")); 
    Iterator<String> itr = tmplist.keySet().iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) 
    {
        String key = itr.next();
        System.out.println(key+""+tmplist.get(key));  // ---- Fails here. java.util.LinkedHashMap 
                                                    //cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    }
```

Do not want to manually extract values as below
        String colorblind = js.get("prefs.colorBlind").toString();
        System.out.println("Color Blind is "+colorblind);

Please suggest how can I fix the code such that I can extract the complete preferences.

Comment: Edit your question and provide valid JSON.

Comment: Updated, please assist.

Answer (score -1):

Your JSON starts with JSON Array, so when you use "get" method you will get `List<>` of something.
Using your code you would get `List<LinkedHashMap<>>`.

You shouldn't use a specific map implementation. Instead, you should use an interface so JsonPath can figure out which map implementation is the best like this:
`List<Map<>>`

Another thing is generic arguments in the `Map<>`. `prefs` JSON Object contains both, Strings and Booleans. Using generic arguments of Map as `<String, String>` you expose yourself to `ClassCastException`. Instead, you should use `Object` and figure out which type is it.

Here's the implementation of how to print out keys and values of `prefs` JSON Object:

Older versions of Java:

```
    List<Map<String, Object>> prefs = path.get("prefs");
    for (Map<String, Object> pref : prefs) {
      for (String key : pref.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(String.format("key: %s | value: %s", key, pref.get(key)));
      }
    }
```

Since Java 1.8 we can use Streams

```
    List<Map<String, Object>> prefs = path.get("prefs");
    prefs.forEach(map -> map.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(String.format("key: %s | value: %s", key, value))));
```